# Border bottom and the header move together

Tags: html, css, header, margin, nav

In my nav, I am separating my section with some text and a horizontal line. For each section this repeats. I am doing this as shown below:

```
.navSectionHeader {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6c6c6c;
}

/*.navSectionHeader::after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #6c6c6c;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
}*/
```

The issue is, my text is now pretty much stuck to the left of the parent div. It should be with some margin to the left while keeping the bottom border start from 0px to the left. When I try to move it with `margin-left: 5px;` it ends up moving the `border-bottom` as well. I tried this with `::after` as shown in the commented bit, adding `!important` to the end but nothing changes. Am I doing this the wrong way? Sorry, I'm a front-end noob!

**Edit:** The section header is in a `<span>` if it makes a difference.

[image: Without margin]

[image: With margin]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `padding` instead of `margin`.

```
.navSectionHeader {
   padding-left: 5px;
}
```

An example to see difference,

```css
div {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 20px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   background: red;
   color: white;
}

.padding { 
   padding-left: 5px;
}

.margin { 
   margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin">margin</div><br>
<div class="padding">padding</div>
```